# Python : Geting issue on OCR while using python tesseract API interface

Tags: linux, python-3.x, ocr, opencv, python

I used Pytesseract module for OCR. It seems slow process. So I followed
[Pytesseract is too slow. How can I make it process images faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52070514/pytesseract-is-too-slow-how-can-i-make-it-process-images-faster) .

I used code mentioned in https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/tesseract-ocr/xvTFjYCDRQU/rCEwjZL3BQAJ . But getting error 
`!strcmp(locale, "C"):Error:Assert failed:in file baseapi.cpp, line 201
Segmentation fault (core dumped)`,
Then i check some post and get reference to add in my code `locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, "C")`.

So after added this in my code I got another error

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "master_doc_test3.py", line 107, in <module>
    tess = Tesseract()
  File "master_doc_test3.py", line 67, in __init__
    if self._lib.TessBaseAPIInit3(self._api, datapath, language):
ctypes.ArgumentError: argument 3: <class 'TypeError'>: wrong type`
```

Can anyone give idea about this error? OR If anyone have idea about best way to  make OCR in fastest way using python.

Answer (score 1):

You should try to convert to bytes every parameter you pass to ctypes lib calls:

```
self._lib.TessBaseAPIInit3(self._api, datapath, language)
```

Something like this is working for me:

```
self._lib.TessBaseAPIInit3(self._api, bytes(datapath, encoding='utf-8'), bytes(language, encoding='utf-8'))
```

I have got the clue [here](https://github.com/sergiomsilva/alpr-unconstrained/issues/73#issuecomment-526508256).
Please, take into consideration that the code you are using needs more fine tuning in other lib calls as the next ones:

```
tess.set_variable(bytes("tessedit_pageseg_mode", encoding='utf-8'), bytes(str(frame_piece.psm), encoding='utf-8'))
tess.set_variable(bytes("preserve_interword_spaces", encoding='utf-8'), bytes(str(1), encoding='utf-8'))
```

Comment: https://stackoverflow.com/a/45269679/5033247