# Python speed up Pytesseract / Use native tesseract library in Python

Tags: python, tesseract, python-tesseract

I use the

```
import cv2,pyautogui,numpy as np
img=np.array(pyautogui.screenshot())
pytesseract.image_to_string(img, lang='eng')
```

command to get the python wrapper for tesseract to get text from an image for me, which goes through the cli interface basically to save the image to a file and then convert it, which is understandably slow (0.2 seconds on a PC, 3 seconds on a raspberry pi per image).

How do I call the native tesseract library (preferably in python) to directly process an OpenCV/PIL image without going through the CLI?

I have looked into the code here:
https://groups.google.com/forum/?utm_medium=email&utm_source=footer#!msg/tesseract-ocr/xvTFjYCDRQU/rCEwjZL3BQAJ as sugguested by [Pytesseract is too slow. How can I make it process images faster?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/52070514/pytesseract-is-too-slow-how-can-i-make-it-process-images-faster) ,and I can't get any output, even with improvements to get the code from start to finish :

1. add locale:

   import locale
   locale.setlocale(locale.LC_ALL, 'C')
2. change all tess.set_variable("tessedit_pageseg_mode", str(frame_piece.psm)) input values to byte:

   tess.set_variable(b"tessedit_pageseg_mode", str.encode(str(frame_piece.psm)))

Anyone have any ideas? Would like something that works on windows as well as linux, but I can probably work with anything that works.

P.S. I have tried image>grayscale>threshold>binarization before handing the image to pytesseract and that does give a decent speed boost over using color images, but even then with the IO write involved, it is slow.